# Automatic Coloring of text when typing in a contenteditable div

Tags: html

What I wanted to do is

When I input text into this content editable section I want those text to be auto colored. Like a theme. Like in visual studio code. When I input text should be colored. Do You guys know a way to implement this thing?

HTML -

```
<section id="js-play" contenteditable="true"></section>
```

Comment: could try searching on google? third result got me https://codepen.io/brianmearns/pen/YVjZWw
this could help you understand other try other editor plugins.

Comment: Thanks alot Friend. Thx Thx Thx. That's what I was looking For

Comment: That's pretty complicated. Have you tried Googling?